# How to load some namespace in Extjs?

Tags: extjs4

I'm trying to load "Ext.ux.CheckColumn" and using the following code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
Ext.require(['Ext.ux.CheckColumn', '*']);
```

The Ext scripts are located at:

```
/Scripts/Library/Ext
```

The ux folder is at:

```
/Scripts/Library/Ext/ux
```

My script in which I'm using loader is located at:

```
/Scripts/MyApp/Module/jsFile.js
```

And my web page is located at:

```
/moudleFolder/mypage.aspx
```

I'm getting error: `namespace is undefined`

PS: I'm using Ext4 and I'm using the above code snippet outside of ready method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that all relative paths are relative to the current HTML document.([docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-paths))

So, I believe in your case you should replace your path with:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../Scripts/Library/Ext/ux');
```

Comment: @wasimbhalli, is the source file 'path/to/ux/CheckColumn.js' loaded? If no, check what url brawser is using for loading this source file (you can do it in google chrome in network tab of developer tools)

Comment: Yes, I was missing the source files. Thanks! :)

Comment: how to minify ext.ux package into single js file?
tried sencha compile exclude --all and include --class 'Ext.ux.*' and concatenate --compress ./ext-ux.js

but compiled file dint have ext.ux.livesearchgridpanel